# How to change the color of text between two positions?

Tags: java, swing, colors, highlight

I want to change the color of my text for my Swing app (JTextPane) from two points, when highlighted. If the user highlights a phrase from, say, index 4 to 9, then only those characters will change their colors, permanently. I say permanently because I already know there is a `setSelectionColor()` option, but that is only temporary. I have managed to get the starting and ending points of the highlighted text, but I've reached a dead end.

Here is what I have so far:

```
StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
AttributeSet attributes = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, color);

    if(tp.getSelectedText() != null){//tp is a jtextpane. text is highlighted. change highlighted text color
        int start = tp.getSelectionStart();
        int end = tp.getSelectionEnd();
        //update the color of the text within start and end
    }
tp.setCharacterAttributes(attributes, false);//update the color for the new text
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have managed to get the starting and ending points of the highlighted text,

You can set the attributes of the text with something like:

```
//  Define a keyword attribute

SimpleAttributeSet keyWord = new SimpleAttributeSet();
StyleConstants.setForeground(keyWord, Color.RED);
StyleConstants.setBackground(keyWord, Color.YELLOW);
StyleConstants.setUnderline(keyWord, Boolean.TRUE );
StyleConstants.setBold(keyWord, true);

//  Change attributes on some text

StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
doc.setCharacterAttributes(start, end - start, keyWord, false);
```

You can also use a `StyledEditorKit` Action to stylize text (bold, italic, color...). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: Thank you! How can I go back to the original font color after the text is highlighted? How can I get the current font color of the text? I think I would use that to revert back to the previous font color, after coloring the highlight text.

Comment: @swagantiswag, use an empty `SimpleAttributeSet`. Read the API for the proper parameters.

Comment: Hello. I need to set foreground of text to a custom color. Then and only then. It doesnt work.